# Error building gdal with built-from-source geotiff library

Tags: mingw, gdal, msys, geotiff

I'm trying to build `gdal 1.9.2` from source. The system is a `Windows 7 64 bits` and I'm working in the `msys` environment.

I have already successfully build `zlib 1.2.7`, `jpeg9a`, `proj 4.8.0`, `tiff`, `geotiff 1.4.0` and `geos 3.4.2`.

Now, when configuring `gdal` with this:

```
./configure --prefix=/d/PRUEBAS/LIBS/gdal_1.9.2/install/ --with-libz=/d/PRUEBAS/LIBS/zlib-1.2.7/install/lib --with-jpeg=/d/PRUEBAS/LIBS/libjpeg9a/install/bin --with-libtiff=/d/PRUEBAS/LIBS/libtiff/install_with_jpeg/bin --with-geos=/d/PRUEBAS/LIBS/geos_3.4.2/install/bin/geos-config  --with-static-proj4=/d/PRUEBAS/LIBS/proj_4.8.0/install/lib
```

I got this (trimmed a bit to show the relevant parts):

```
GDAL is now configured for i686-pc-mingw32
  LIBTOOL support:           yes

  LIBZ support:              external
  LIBLZMA support:           no
  GRASS support:             no
  CFITSIO support:           no
  PCRaster support:          internal
  LIBPNG support:            internal
  GTA support:               no
  LIBTIFF support:           external (BigTIFF=no)
  LIBGEOTIFF support:        internal
  LIBJPEG support:           external
  GEORASTER support:         no
  GEOS support:              yes

  SWIG Bindings:          no

  Statically link PROJ.4:    yes
  enable OGR building:       yes
  enable pthread support:    yes
  enable POSIX iconv support:no, consider installing GNU libiconv
  hide internal symbols:     no
```

So I understand all is configured properly, as the libraries I built from source are *detected* and appear as *external*.

Now, if I try to build `gdal` with `geotiff`:

```
 --with-geotiff=/d/PRUEBAS/LIBS/libgeotiff_1.4.0/install/lib/libgeotiff
```

I end up with this message:

```
checking for libtiff... using libtiff from /d/PRUEBAS/LIBS/libtiff/install_with_jpeg/bin.
checking for TIFFScanlineSize64 in -ltiff... no
checking for XTIFFClientOpen in -lgeotiff... no
checking for XTIFFClientOpen in -lgeotiff... (cached) no
configure: error: We require at least GeoTIFF 1.2.1. Consider using the one supplied with GDAL
```

I've been struggling with this for a while and I didn't find a way to solve it.
Do you have any idea on how to solve this?

**NOTE:**
Some libraries are static-only: `zlib`, `libgeotiff`, `tiff`.

The others are available as static and dynamic libraries.

The static libraries are in: `path_to_the_installation/lib`.

The dynamic libraries are in: `path_to_the_installation/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some help for Linux configuration from GDAL's site:
http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingOnUnix

I know this isn't the system you're actually on, but since you are using GCC and MinGW there is a 'Caveat' bullet point in there covering a similar-sounding failure that might apply to you. Namely, that "configure" script isn't too bright about library versions.

So, you can try their advised workaround and set "--with-geotiff=internal".

Beyond that, I'd try hunting down where it produces those lines that you see before "configure: error:". Its a script, so you should be able to see what its doing in a text editor (and even play w/ changing it to make it work for you).

Comment: I need the external one. Other libs are using that GeoTiff. But I'll check those scripts and see if I find the offending lines.